# Explanation of document.BaseURI behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

While debugging some javascript code in chrome, I've faced with next thing:

if pass to xhr.open relative url (say "mail.fpp?a=123sd") like this

```
xhr.open("post", "mail.fpp?a=123sd", true)
```

request will be sent on

```
https://www.somedomain.com/mail/mail.fpp?a=123sd
```

All fine and dandy, but document.URI (and document.location.toString()) has value

```
https://www.somedomain.com/default.aspx?id=12345
```

I've noticed that baseURI has value

```
https://www.somedomain.com/mail/
```

but according with [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_baseuri.asp) document.BaseURI readonly.

Why does document.URI (or document.location.toString()) unequal document.BaseURI? What does cause such unequality?

Comment: Does your HTML document have a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is easy, there is base tag. Thahk you  apsillers